# onmouseover transition with map area with multiple images

Tags: javascript, css, dictionary, css-transitions, onmouseover

So I have a pie-nav, divided into 6 sections, when I hover over every section using the map tool, it highlights it and change the color of the other sections, I did this the easy way using 6 images, so when I use onmouseover the whole image changes and gives the impression of the selector effect. However, I just want to add simple transition. I can use css transitions for 2 images, but here I'm using 6 images and specific area shape.

```
<img src="assets/img/default.png" usemap="#Map" id="main-img">
<map name="Map">
  <area shape="poly" onmouseover="document.getElementById('main-img').src = 'assets/img/image1.png';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('main-img').src = 'assets/img/default.png';" coords="40,126,115,42,215,4,255,4,260,102,187,130,127,177" href="#">
  <area shape="poly" onmouseover="document.getElementById('main-img').src = 'assets/img/image2.png';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('main-img').src = 'assets/img/default.png';" coords="32,384,121,337,103,267,123,186,31,135,2,233,5,314" href="#">
  <area shape="poly" onmouseover="document.getElementById('main-img').src = 'assets/img/image3.png';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('main-img').src = 'assets/img/default.png';" coords="32,384,121,337,103,267,123,186,31,135,2,233,5,314" href="#">
  <area shape="poly" onmouseover="document.getElementById('main-img').src = 'assets/img/image4.png';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('main-img').src = 'assets/img/default.png';" coords="32,384,121,337,103,267,123,186,31,135,2,233,5,314" href="#">
  <area shape="poly" onmouseover="document.getElementById('main-img').src = 'assets/img/image5.png';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('main-img').src = 'assets/img/default.png';" coords="32,384,121,337,103,267,123,186,31,135,2,233,5,314" href="#">
  <area shape="poly" onmouseover="document.getElementById('main-img').src = 'assets/img/image6.png';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('main-img').src = 'assets/img/default.png';" coords="32,384,121,337,103,267,123,186,31,135,2,233,5,314" href="#">
</map>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kkjjqfkg/

Comment: Answers may vary based on the content of the images.  Can you give two or more examples of _before_ and _after_ states of the mouseover effect  you are attempting?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kkjjqfkg/ here you go @hunteke

Comment: @hunteke just fade in fade out 0.3s, smooth transition nothing big

Comment: My suggestion was going to be along the lines of "Use SVG" and have 12 parts, 6 "on" state and 6 "off" state. Then, use the :hover pseudo element and transitions. But I, too, am having a difficult time with the logic given you're overlapping center area.  For time's sake, I might use a secondary image as the transition area and transition that.

Comment: @hunteke sorry, how can i use a secondary image as the transition?

Answer (score 0):

Yo, you could create a css file and import it.

```
img{
  transition: 1s;
}
```